# Workflow management for nosql database

Tags: java, workflow, workflow-engine, nosql

Are there any good workflow management engines which support NoSQL databases as well? Most of the popular ones do not. Is there any way around it?

Comment: I hate to beg for acceptance, but if you saw the answer and if you like it, you should accept it, otherwise you won't get answers anymore in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Talend Open Studio for Big Data](https://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio). It has lots of NoSQL connectors, it is open source and its quite easy to design workflows.